# MDX calculation for count of sum within a range

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a cube in SSAS with the following measures:

```
NameID
Number
Date
```

NameID points to a Person dimension with a Name string (there can be multiple records with the same NameID). Date points to a server-side date dimension.

I'm looking for an MDX calculation I can include in the cube that will show the count of Person.Names where the sum of the Measure.Number fields for the date range given in the query is within a certain range (say 0-10, 11-20, etc).

I've tried various flavors of COUNT(), FILTER() and SUM(), but my MDX is rusty, and I'm missing something.

Comment: It sounds like you need discretization. Is this what you're trying to do? http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3809096/Introduction-to-Attribute-Discretization.htm

Answer (score 1):

MDX has no histogram features, we're thinking about adding this in [icCube](http://www.iccube.com/), but at this point in time there is nothing out of the box in MDX. You can read this [article](http://tomislav.piasevoli.com/2009/07/24/implementing-histograms-in-olap/) for a solution in SSAS.

Besides you can create a calculated member with count and filter, but I believe you already did this.

The problem defining this in a hierarchy is that it won't work as expected with filters. Imagine you wan't this ranges for a particular year. But if your ranges are fixed, creating a dimension/hierarchy might be also solution.